# What minimum version of .NET can I expect on client machines?

Tags: .net

I know that in general I can expect .NET 2.0 or better installed on most client/customer machines since it's been included in Windows XP SP1 (SP2?) for some time and comes standard in Vista/2003/2008. But my question now is, can I expect .NET 3.0 to support WCF/WPF? We build component libraries so we can't make too many assumptions and requiring that the our development customers include the 3.0 installer is not ideal.

So the question I guess is, in your experience what is the minimum version of .NET installed on most machines that have .NET installed? Is there a resource that tracks this sort of thing?

To clarify: I do not have any control or influence over the final intstaller. I'm interested in what dependencies are already in place not what to do to bring the client machine up to spec.

Comment: Why ask this question? Why would you ever assume critical pieces are already on a random client? If you're an IT shop writing for internal users is the only time you can assume, since your desktop engineering team can force a standard.

Comment: It's not about delivery without bounds to a client machine. It's about minimum system requirements. I don't control the installer. I want to know what minimum system requirements other developers are targeting to determine if it's worth adding .NET 3.0 dependent features or not.

Comment: [Windows is not a .NET Framework delivery channel](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/04/04/10149346.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my experience, you can pretty safely assume 2.0 at this point.  Assuming versions higher than that always seems to get us into trouble.  (On the other hand, just ptoviding a link to the 3.5 installer is pretty easy and painless.)

Answer (score 5):

**Never assume anything about a client machine**.

It is easy enough to bundle your target framework with the install if the client requires it.

Comment: +1 if you're already deploying to client machines, you can deploy the necessary framework.

Comment: The problem is that I do not provide the installer. Customers that use our library provide the installer. Thus we would be requiring each of our customers to also include the installer.

Comment: @Paul then provide your customers guidance to building a kickass installer that can cleanly and painlessly upgrade .NET when necessary. What an awesome value-add!

Answer (score -1):

You should implement something like [browsercheck](https://www.cyscape.com/showbrow.aspx?bhcp=1) on your site to collect all the browser stats. In this way the analytics will speak for itself and there is not need for any assumptions.