# Would you avoid using a component that requires .NET 3.5?

Tags: .net

In a follow up to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762762/what-minimum-version-of-net-can-i-expect-on-client-machines), would you avoid using a component library that required .NET 3.0/3.5? Would the additional install requirements be too much to ask or, is the .NET installer easy enough to just include or link to that it doesn't matter?

Comment: How is this different than the other question?

Comment: The solution to the other question is to simply require that developer customers include the 3.0 installer or link to it for their products. This question is intended to determine if that's a burden that developers would simply ignore - or if it's significant enough that they'd avoid using the libraries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me it is more a question of *when* rather then *if*. Lets face it, virtually everyone will be upgraded to .NET 3.5 sometime, if not already.

Quite frankly, there is no good reason I can think of why a Windows computer should not be upgraded to .NET 3.5.

That having been said, if I had a client that for some reason refused to accept any software that required .NET 3, then I would have to accomodate them if I expected to get paid.

As for the installer, it really is no bigger deal to install the latest .NET then it is to install .NET 2.

Comment: Where would you draw the line?  If .NET 48.8 requires Windows 7 do you simply buy into the Microsoft will get it out there attitude?  Many organizations restrict rights on boxes due to viruses, instability, and the like.

Comment: If employees start installing random software on their work machines the admin has done something seriously wrong. You can easily push those things via group policies which is very painless.

Answer (score 2):

I might avoid the component under several circumstances.  The ease of use of the .NET runtime upgrades is not the only factor. If your application is going to be used in a corporate setting or you do not have a technical audience I would take a lowest common denominator attitude.  If your audience is less constrained you may have some justification to lean the other direction.  Another important factor are the features the component brings to your application.  If the feature is significant enough or important enough weigh that against the users time in configuring their environment.  The environment will likely catch up but these other external factors may be important.

Answer (score 2):

Lack of support for Windows 2000 is sometimes a reason to avoid .NET 3.5.

Comment: it seems there is a hack to enable it : http://rainstorms.me.uk/blog/2008/03/12/microsoft-net-framework-35-in-windows-2000/

Comment: Without any exploration of the limitations of this approach, it looks pretty tenuous. Not something I would recommend doing. But, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

It would totally depend on what I was writing.  If I was writing an application that targeted a large consumer base, I would probably stay away from something that required 3.5 because of the size of the download.  If I was writing a Visual Studio 2008 add-in, I'd have no qualms about using something that required 3.5.  If I was writing an internal app, it would depend on the current desktop configuration and how open the IT admin folks were to rolling out 3.5 if it wasn't there already.  You will probably need to as about a more concrete scenario to get a more concrete answer I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real need to avoid. There are lot of tools/installers out there that can make the installation seam less and ubiquitous. Remember you need .NET 3.5 SP1.

Note: Your clients need to have administrator privileges to do install .Net if it is not already present. This can sometimes pose a problem in terms of angry customers. Remember the article on MLB dissing Silverlight primarily because the users could not install the plug-in as they did not have sufficient privileges at work.